# How to get time since createdAt in mongodb with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I want to know how long it's been since the account was created:

```
console.log('TIMEYWIMEY',req.user.createdAt, new Date(), new Date() - req.user.createdAt)
```

this prints out `TIMEYWIMEY 2019-05-10T16:12:40.457Z 2019-07-26T16:05:58.142Z NaN`

I don't understand why it's NaN, they seem like they're both dates and I thought you could just subtract them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from the question shouldn't you be getting difference of milliseconds from the valid dates and then calculating.

```
const d1 = createdAt.getTime();
const d2 = new Date().getTime();
const diff = d2 - d1;
```

And then from difference convert to your needed unit. For example:

```
const days = diff/1000*60*60*24;
```

Comment: Yeah, this seemed to be what I was missing. Though I did have to wrap createdAt in a new Date() in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the function that takes a string timestamp and returns a string representation of time since the passed timestamp

```
function timeSince(timestamp) {
  let time = Date.parse(timestamp);
  let now = Date.now();
  let secondsPast = (now - time) / 1000;
  let suffix = 'ago';

  let intervals = {
      year: 31536000,
      month: 2592000,
      week: 604800,
      day: 86400,
      hour: 3600,
      minute: 60,
      second: 1
  };

  for (let i in intervals) {
        let interval = intervals[i];
        if (secondsPast >= interval) {
            let count = Math.floor(secondsPast / interval);
            return `${count} ${i} ${count > 1 ? 's' : ''} ${suffix}`;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this function like this:

```
let timestamp = '2023-01-11T09:02:24.566Z';
console.log(timeSince(timestamp));
```

This will return something like:

```
0 seconds ago
```